# Form Submission Goes To Javascript - And Stay On Same Page

Tags: javascript, html

Please consider the following non-working HTML document:

```
<html> 
    <body>
        <form action="" method="GET" onsubmit="return f(this);">
            <input type="text" name="bar" value="" />
            <input type="button" name="foo" value="foo" />
        </form>
    </body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function f(x) {
            alert(x.bar);
        }
    </script>
</html>
```

What I am trying to achieve is that when either (a) the foo button is pressed; or (b) enter is pressed while the text input has focus; then the function f is called with the content of the s text input - and the browser should otherwise stay on the same page after f returns.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What exactly does not work with that document?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use a submit input rather than a button input, and to get the text from text input you use the value property and return false to prevent the form from submitting

```
<html>
    <body>
        <form action="" method="GET" onsubmit="return f(this);">
            <input type="text" name="bar" value="" />
            <input type="submit" name="foo" value="foo"/>
        </form>
        <script type="text/javascript">
                function f(x)
                {
                    alert(x.bar.value);
                    return false;
                }
        </script>
        </body>
</html>
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/W3Neg/)

Answer (score 0):

Just call it with the value instead of the form element?

```
onsubmit="return f(this.bar.value);"
```

To prevent the sending of that page, you can return `false` from `f`.

But it would be much cleaner to use a proper event handler instead of that onsubmit-attribute. Read more on them [here](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html).

```
<html>
    <body>
        <form id="inputform" action="" method="GET">
            <input type="text" name="bar" value="" />
            <input type="button" name="foo" value="foo"/>
        </form>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        function f(x) {
            alert(x.bar);
        }
        var form = document.getElementById("inputform");
        form.onsubmit = function(event) {
            var x = f(form.bar.value);
            if (!x)
                event.preventDefault();
        };
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```